# Can I use Apache mod_auth_openidc with with an non compliant Authorization Server?

Tags: apache, oauth-2.0, openid, mod-auth-openidc, authorization-server

We've been using a custom Oauth2 Authorization Server together with some SpringBoot applications for a couple of years.

Now there is a demand to integrate the authentication of a legacy php application. I have done some research and found the [OpenId Module for Apache](https://github.com/OpenIDC/mod_auth_openidc). I managed to configure it successfully and initiate the **authorization code flow**.

The problem occurs when the auth server redirects back to my application:

*OpenID Connect Provider error: Error in handling response type.*

Reading this [issue](https://github.com/OpenIDC/mod_auth_openidc/issues/215) I understand that the problem happens because the authorization server does not return the *id_token* (it also does not accept an 'openid' scope). We don't want to change it just to attend a legacy application.

On the other side I can see that the correct **authorization code** is present at the callback, if the module just let me continue I could grab the token aftwards and solve our issue.

Is there any way to avoid this error without changing the authorization server?

This is the configuration I am using:

```
OIDCProviderJwksUri https://myauthserver/.well-known/jwks.json
OIDCProviderAuthorizationEndpoint https://myauthserver/oauth/authorize
OIDCClientID myclientId
OIDCClientSecret 12345
OIDCScope "all"
OIDCResponseType "code"
OIDCRedirectURI /protected
#OIDCRedirectURI http://myRedirectUrl
OIDCCryptoPassphrase SOMEPASSPHRASE
```

Comment: OpenID is a superset of OAuth2. If you have an OAuth2 server, it will miss many features that OpenID has.

Comment: @Evert I do not need OpenId. Just using this module because was the only Apache/Oauth solution that appeared. Is there any alternative to authenticate an Apache based application using Oauth2?

Comment: If you've googled and haven't found it, then probably not. Personally I would put application logic in PHP, not apache.